# Session::flash is not working in Laravel version 5.2.27

Tags: forms, laravel

I am trying to display a success message upon form submit in Laravel.

However, it doesn't work.

I've added `use Session;` at the top of the controller file, the routes are in the middleware and the configuration in config/session.php is the default one.

My controller function is able to save in the database without any problem :

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {

        $post = new Post;
        $post->title = $request->title;
        $post->description = $request->description;
        $post->slug = $request->slug;
        $post->body = $request->body;

        $post->save();

        Session::flash('success', 'SUCCESS MESSAGE GOES HERE'); 

        return redirect()->route('posts.show', $post->id);

    }
```

here is my template file :

```
@if(Session::has('success'))
<div class="alert-box success">
    <h2>{{ Session::get('success') }}</h2>
</div>
@endif
```

My routes :

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function() {
Route::get('/', 'PagesController@getIndex');
Route::resource('posts','PostController');
});
```

Is see there is no success in the session file.  I cannot figure out why exactly :

```
a:4:{s:6:"_token";s:40:"EntXIr9tkqAcKarDZhaNxKb6RfcFdFV9ZtF6W7kU";s:9:"_previous";a:1:{s:3:"url";s:30:"http://localhost:8000/posts/35";}s:5:"flash";a:2:{s:3:"old";a:0:{}s:3:"new";a:0:{}}s:9:"_sf2_meta";a:3:{s:1:"u";i:1459467699;s:1:"c";i:1459467699;s:1:"l";s:1:"0";}}
```

Someone can help me figure out what the problem is?

Comment: Laravel version 5.2.27

Comment: Is it a fresh install? What is on your routes.php file?

Answer (score 1):

The `web` middleware no longer needs to be explicitly applied to routes in your routes.php file. It is now silently applied to routes within `app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php`, as per [this change](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/commit/5c30c98db96459b4cc878d085490e4677b0b67ed?diff=split) in Laravel 5.2.27

Previously you would be required to explicitly apply the `web` middleware to routes like so:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('welcome');
    });
});
```

The above can now be achieved like so:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the route is using the "web" middleware to access session data.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {

    Route::get('foo', 'FooController@bar'); // session data should be available here
});
```

Comment: Yeah, I'm thinking this is the problem, there was a [recent change](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/commit/5c30c98db96459b4cc878d085490e4677b0b67ed) where they extracted that middleware to the [RouteServiceProvider](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/5c30c98db96459b4cc878d085490e4677b0b67ed/app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php#L54).

Comment: Hi,  yes, my routes are in the group middleware.  I've updated the question a couple minute ago with this info.

Comment: Ok.  I needed to REMOVE the routes from the group Middleware :)  Thank you so much srubmx for the answer :)